# make a readonly field as a writable after workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a list, with a readonly field, I want that the user can edit that field after the workflow is complete, only using sharepoint designer.
It is posible?

Comment: what field is read-only, and how is it read-only?

Answer (score 1):

If the field is set as read only in code behind, the only way is through code behind.

Even if you tried to change it with JavaScript or something akin, you won't get the desired effect because of the validation.

You will need a code behind solution with visual studio.